Confusion on 1 bit precession
We know binary representation of $\frac{1}{3}=0.010101..$. What will its 1  bits precession $0.0$ or 0.1? Note that $0.1=\frac{1}{2}$ is closer to $\frac{1}{3}$ than $0.0=0$.

Please define what you mean by "precession" and "1 bit precession"

Perhaps the OP wants to ask how the number should be correctly rounded to 1 bit of precision rather than precession.
